# How to continuously check the value of an input using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

I have an input that is empty after page load, and if a user suddenly fill a value on it the value of the two inputs on the if condition should change to.

My problem is when I fill an input, the if condition result doesn't changed in real time.

script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var countTimerEmailName = setInterval(
            function ()
            {
            emailName();    
            }, 500);        
    function emailName(){

            if($('#emailCodeResult').val() != '' || $('#email').val() == ''){
                clearInterval(countTimerEmailName);
            }

            $.ajax({
            url:"view.php",
            type:"GET",
            data: { term : $('#email').val() },
            dataType:"JSON",
            success: function(result) {


            }

        });

    };
    });
```

Comment: u can use `onkeyup` event

Comment: afaik `okeyup` event wont fire on touch devices

Comment: In that case use a function that is called after say every 1sec and checks if the value has changed

Answer (score 3):

Fire your function on change

```
$('#inputA, #inputB').change(function(){
  if($('#inputA').val() != '' || $('#inputB').val() == '') {
   alert("True");
  }else{
    alert("False");
  }
})
```

Comment: is their another way to make it work? my script functions wont work if i used ur code.

Comment: i edit my script please have a look. I want to constantly check the value of email if its empty or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `keyup` like this:

```
$('#textboxID').on( 'keyup', function () {

//write your code here

});
```

For touch devices as rzr siad keyup won't occur.
You can write a function that is called every, say 1 sec or whatever, like this:

```
    t1=window.setInterval(function(){foo()},1000);
function foo()
{
// write function definition here
}
```

or use `blur` as others suggested, if the you want to check value only after the user is done with that textbox and moves to next field.

Comment: i edited my script..i want to constantly check the value of #email so that the if condition can change result.

Comment: try using: $('#emailCodeResult').val().length == 0

Comment: I think `onkeyup` would bethe best choice in that case

Answer (score 0):

```js
var fieldcheck;

$(function() {
  $("#input").focus(function() {
    fieldcheck = setInterval(function() {
      var innerValue = $("#input").val();
    
      if (innerValue == "") {
        // Your code          
      } else {
        // Your code
      }
    }, 100);
  });

  $("#input").blur(function() {
    clearInterval(fieldcheck);        
  });
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.